# with Scrapy, I can't scrape a website for unknown reason (maybe because some kind of redirecting)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape ntry.com 
it's main page's url is 
ntry.com/#/main.php ,

and the specific page I want to scrape is 
http://ntry.com/#/scores/named_ladder/main.php

But for a reason I don't know, I can't scrape the wrong page. Here is my code.

```
import scrapy


class NtrySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "ntry"
allowed_domains = ["ntry.com"]
start_urls = [
    "http://ntry.com/#/scores/named_ladder/main.php"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    filename = 'ntryex1'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

'
    DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://ntry.com/#/scores/named_ladder/main.html> (referer: None)

using this code, I always scrape contents on ntry.com/#/main.php, though my start_urls is http://ntry.com/#/scores/named_ladder/main.php.

Could you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: probably this page uses JavaScript to load subpages so you will need Selenium or other tool  to load page and run JavaScript. Scrapy should work with Selenium.

Comment: Selenium might be overhead ... it depends on what information do you want to parse from there (look through Network panel in browser and investigate from where each part comes)

Comment: Remember that any part after `#` is a client anchor and is not transferred to the server. The actual URL retrieved will be just `ntry.com`, and the rest is handled by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

scrapy by default doesn't load java script .. try disabling java script in your browser and open your required URL, Scrapy is actually receving that reponse which comes in your browser after disabling java script ..

if you wants to process javascript with scrapy have a look on  [Splash](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/)